# Object.values() for an object that its properties are an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this:

```
let errorMessages = {
    firstName: [
      "It is too short",
      "Only English characters are valid"
    ],
    lastName: [
      "This field is required",
      "Only English characters are valid"
    ]
};
```

The result of `Object.values(errorMessages)` is:

```
[["It is too short", "Only English characters are valid"], ["This field is required", "Only English characters are valid"]]
```

But I want

```
["It is too short", "Only English characters are valid", "This field is required", "Only English characters are valid"]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) that will concatenate all sub-arrays:

```
Object.values(errorMessages).flat()
```